# mysql_real_escape_string() occur ristriction to view google map

Tags: php, mysql, html, google-maps

I paste google map code

```
<iframe width="186" height="186" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=NIPA,+Karachi,+Pakistan&daddr=&hl=en&geocode=FXg3fAEd6dH_AyF_rsIkOA6mpg&aq=&sll=24.91788,67.097065&sspn=0.007414,0.009645&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=24.91788,67.097065&spn=0.007414,0.009645&output=embed"></iframe>
<br />
<small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=embed&saddr=NIPA,+Karachi,+Pakistan&daddr=&hl=en&geocode=FXg3fAEd6dH_AyF_rsIkOA6mpg&aq=&sll=24.91788,67.097065&sspn=0.007414,0.009645&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=24.91788,67.097065&spn=0.007414,0.009645" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small> </div>
```

in a text area and using `mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST'map']))`

but on fetching back from mysql table it does not show map because of **SQL Injection** protection function ie: **mysql_real_escape_string()** like:

```
<iframe width=\"186\" height=\"186\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=NIPA,+Karachi,+Pakistan&daddr=&hl=en&geocode=FXg3fAEd6dH_AyF_rsIkOA6mpg&aq=&sll=24.91788,67.097065&sspn=0.007414,0.009645&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=24.91788,67.097065&spn=0.007414,0.009645&output=embed\"></iframe>
<br />
<small><a href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=embed&saddr=NIPA,+Karachi,+Pakistan&daddr=&hl=en&geocode=FXg3fAEd6dH_AyF_rsIkOA6mpg&aq=&sll=24.91788,67.097065&sspn=0.007414,0.009645&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=24.91788,67.097065&spn=0.007414,0.009645\" style=\"color:#0000FF;text-align:left\">View Larger Map</a></small> </div>
```

.............!

Comment: so what's the problem? or the question?

Comment: Can you please a) include the HTML / Javascript page and b) the PHP

Comment: @Octopus-Paul, the problem is `magic-quotes`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try applying `stripslashes()` to the string before displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `magic-quotes` enabled.
This is one of the big mistakes in php (and will be taken out of the language in version 5.something).
In many older setups it is still enabled and it's a good idea to disable it, because it does not add any security, but it does add a lot of headaches.

If (and only if) you cannot disable it, you can use `stripslashes()` before doing `mysql_real_escape_string`.